# Does using the Google URL shortener add anything to utm_ tracking tags in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, url-parameters, url-shorteners, utm-parameters

I scanned a qr code from a competitor today, and they used the googl URL shortner.  Though the destination was a facebook page, not an actual website, I noticed that there weren't any parameters attached to the URL.

And even though this didn't apply to the URL, it got me wondering if there are any advantages to using the Google URL shortener and it's [API](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/getting_started) as opposed to using something like bit.ly when sending utm tracking codes to Google Analytics, such as hiding the `utm_` codes from competitors.

Comment: The main reason why I use goo.gl is that it allows quick access using my Google account (which I'm invariably signed into) and provides the basic reporting i need, without requiring me to sign in to yet another service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google's URL shortener does not have any extra features that allow cloaking of parameters after they are clicked. If anything the Google service has less features than some of the other options like Bit.ly but not any clear advantages or disadvantages.